# How do I calculate new minimal speed for a glider when I put water into the tank?

Tags: glider, weight, polar-curve

Lets say a glider weights 400kg and has a minimal speed of 70km/h.

When it has additionally 100l water, so in total 500kg, what is the new minimal speed?

I would argue, that in order to reach the same point in the polar diagram, we have to scale according to

$v_2 = v_1 \cdot \sqrt{m_2/m_1}$

because drag and lift forces scale quadratic with speed.

The result would be 78km/h.

However, in the theory we learn

$v_2 = v_1 \cdot m_2/m_1 = 87km/h$

Q: Isn't that wrong?

Comment: If the water tank(s) are original equipment on the glider, you will always find the answer to this in the operating handbook.

Comment: That's clear, but doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Fair enough. So let's go back to the  beginning. What do you mean by "minimal speed"? I am a glider pilot and we don't use that term. Do you mean stall speed? Or ??

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. Your calculation is correct. Where did you find the equation you refer to as being "in the theory"?

Comment: Lift is related to airspeed, all other things equal, by v squared. Hence, your calculation is OK, and that 'in the theory' is clearly wrong...

Comment: The "theory" appears to be regarding momentum, not used to calculate lift.  Lift is proportional to the square of speed.  Speed squared is also applicable to the kinetic energy state of your aircraft, which can put you on    the far side of the runway if you land too fast.

Comment: It might be a safety thing. You can probably do that calculation in your head, but I bet most people don't take calculators when they go flying, and square root would be harder to calculate. The aim of the minimum speed is to prevent you from crashing, so if the theory gives you a higher one, and an easier equation to use on the field, you are safer.

Answer (score 1):

$v_2 = v_1 \cdot \sqrt{m_2/m_1}$ is the correct formula.

$v_2 = v_1 \cdot m_2/m_1 = 87km/h$ is simply wrong, possible that it is only a typing mistake, but it is wrong just the same.